# check Network in Service

Tags: android, service

I have method, which checks the availability of the Internet(it is working)

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    final NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    final NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (mobile.isAvailable() || wifi.isAvailable() && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I need to check the presence of the Internet in a service that runs in the background. How can I do it ?

I am tried this, but calling the error
"System services not available to Activities before onCreate()"

Comment: why do you want to check that in a service? if you do it in service you can do any UI related changes. So if there is any function which needs internet access call you function `isConnected()` and then perform your task

Comment: I want to update data from Internet within my Service, which working in background

Comment: so create a simple service and perform your task there